# Android Bluetooth ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT not being received

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am working on an application to connect with Bluetooth device which works on HFP(BluetoothHeadset) protocol.

The Bluetooth headset sends AT(ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT) instruction through Bluetooth HFP. I have successfully established the connection between the devices.

I have written a broadcast receiver and registered it in the manifest.

```
<receiver
            android:name=".BluetoothReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED" />

        </receiver>
```

The above receiver works for all the actions mentioned and the trigger in broadcast except for the

"android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT".

I am unable to receive the headset events which are vendor specific. 
The Bluetooth device sends the data through the above action. I have taken reference from the following docs

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Headset Service broadcasts it? You can check how a vendor specific AT-command is processed in your Android version in Android source code repository. For example, processUnknownAt at [HeadsetStateMachine of Android 8.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-8.1.0_r41/src/com/android/bluetooth/hfp/HeadsetStateMachine.java)

Upd: BTW do you really have no intent-filter closing tag?

Upd2: Because they use addCategory with companyid in intent, you possibly need to describe all required category-es in your manifest too.

Comment: This method gets hit - broadcastVendorSpecificEventIntent . Check line number 2332.

Comment: When will the event be triggered? I want to get the battery information from my headset. But ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT is never triggered even after adding company id